# How many elements of order p (p,q are primes) in finite abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_{q^3}$

Tags: group-theory

How many elements of order p (p,q are primes) in finite abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_{q^3}$?

My answer is:

Edit:

As p is a prime we have p-1 elements of order p in a cyclic group

So we have $(p-1)^2 -1 $

Is this correct?

Comment: No, there are more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p\not = q$:
The subgroup $H_1=\mathbb{Z}_p \times 1 \times 1$ contains already $p-1$ elements of order $p$. The same for $H_2=1 \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times 1$, as those groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
This is due to the fact, that a cyclic group of order $n$ contains $\varphi(n)$ generators of order $n$, where $\varphi$ is the euler-totient-function.
Now any non-trivial element of $H_1H_2$ has order p, which are $p^2-1$ elements.

Comment: OK now. And there are $p^3-1$ if $p=q$.

Comment: thanks, was to fast at first...